# Extracting .exe file using powershell

Tags: powershell, exe, extract, unzip

I am trying to extract .exe file using powershell without any other tools.

I tried to use System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, but that works only for .zip files..

```
$zip_file = Get-Item ("C:\Users\00WORK\gs\gs.exe")
$destination = Get-Item ("C:\Users\tuna")
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zip_file,$destination)
```

Also tried this, but without any success

```
start-process C:\Users\Downloads\gs.exe -Argumentlist "/a"
```

Tried also this but once again without any succes

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace(“C:\Users\00WORK\gs\gs.exe”)
foreach($item in $zip.items())
{
$shell.Namespace(“C:\Users\tuna”).copyhere($item)
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what is gs.exe?  Is this a self-extracting zip file? I would think you could extract the contents by running it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have tried

```
start-process C:\Setup.exe -Argumentlist "/a"
```

Then it is not possible using powershell, this command is completely dependant on how the file was packaged, if all else fails I personally would use a utility like 7-Zip, but as you said you would not like to use utilities.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem recently as well.  Dewi's answer would not have worked for me.  I solved it like this:

```
mv gs.exe gs.zip
Expand-Archive -Path gs.zip
```

Optionally, you can rename it back when you're done, if you need the exe for other purposes.

```
mv gs.zip gs.exe
```

Note that you'll need PowerShell 5 or newer to use Expand-Archive.  Thankfully, this is available as a download all the way back to Win 7 as Microsoft [KB3191566](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah well powershell doesn't recognize all compression algorithms. I am trying to do this with an HP driver pack file which comes in a self extracting .exe file. Even if you change the filename to a .zip it will not extract the files and instead throws a New-Object exception error.